# How to launch and automatically feed commands to a software console?

Tags: perl, console, command, system, vivado

This might seem like an already asked question but I found that it is a rare and still an open problem. My question is dependent on Vivado console but it is not related to Vivado console only, there can be any other console (consider Vivado console as an example only). If there are already solution available, I will be happy to redirected there.

## **Objective:**

My aim is to build a vivado project using tcl commands.

I have a list of all the tcl commands available and I can run those commands very easily in the vivado console. There are two ways to do it in vivado console:

**Method 1:**

1. Launch the command prompt
2. run the following command to launch vivado console

```
vivado -mode tcl
```

3. run the tcl commands one by one like:

```
set project_name "VIV_Project"
set user_project_dir C:/viv
create_project -force $project_name $user_project_dir/projects -part xczu11
```

4. I can continue with all the commands until I execute the last command.

```
exit
```

**Method 2:**

Now there is another way to do it is to put all these commands in a one tcl script (tcl_script.tcl) and run one single command to build the entire project like this:

1. Launch the command prompt
2. run the following command to launch vivado console (batch mode) and run all the commands from a script:

```
vivado -mode batch -source tcl_script.tcl
```

3. wait until script finishes execution

Now the trick part is *"I do not want to give access of the tcl commands to anyone"*. I want them hidden. If I choose the method 1, commands needs to be entered manually onto the vivado console and so my tcl commands are open to the end user.

If I choose the Method 2, my commands are available in a tcl script that is again available in a directory. Vivado console does not support encrupted tcl scripts so I cannot do that either.

I am open to suggestion about how can I still execute my tcl commands without anyone knowing it?
Ideally I want an executable that User can just click that run all the commands and then exit.

## Experiments:

I have tried the following experiments that led to ask this question here:

**Experiment 1:**

I can create the executable of the perl script so I tried to use the perl script `system()` command:

```
system(vivado -mode tcl);
system(set project_name "VIV_Project");
system(set user_project_dir C:/viv);
system(create_project -force $project_name $user_project_dir/projects -part xczu11);
system(exit);
```

I was expecting it to launch the vivado console and then I thought that the next line would feed commands to the vivado console. And if every thing is according to the plan then I can buld an executable of the perl script and user can just launch the executable.

Now the issue with this method is that the `system(vivado -mode tcl);` commands never exits. It launches the vivado console and it stays there waiting for commands to be feed.

**Experiment 2:**
I have tried to used the batch script to run the vivado console and then again ran into the same problem that once vivado is launched, the batch script is waiting for it to return.

This brings me to the question that I asked in the title (so I am going to discuss the details here):

**How to launch and automatically feed commands to a software console?**

## Details on the original Question:

I am using perl script to run the commands via `system()`.

1. I want to the launch the vivado console using some environment (perl or anything else) whose executable I can create in the end.
2. Then I want to give commands to vivado console from that environment. Issue with current perl approach is that `system(vivado -mode tcl);` commands launches the vivado but it never returns and meanwhile the vivado console is expecting some commands.

So how can I use an environment (perl or something) to launch a vivado console and then feed commands to that console?

Plus I am open to suggestion on how can I protect my tcl script? I have only provided one method here.

Thanks

Comment: This is a very long way to phrase a simple question. You cannot use system() this way. Each system call spawns a new shell instance, and it doesn't exit until the process ends. In order to write data to the process, you either have to do it in one system call, or open a pipe handle to which you can write. Or use a module that does it for you. Read perldoc open for more info.

Comment: I didn't read the entire question, so sorry if this doesn't apply, but https://metacpan.org/release/RGIERSIG/Expect-1.15/view/Expect.pod is a module designed to automate actions with an interactive console.

Comment: _Method 2, my commands are available in a tcl script that is again available in a directory_   - If you feed the commands to tcl from a perl script, those commands can be extracted from the perl script.

Comment: See also: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3#How-can-I-hide-the-source-for-my-Perl-program?

Comment: @clamp Does that mean that if I place all my tcl commands in a perl script and then make an executable of that perl script, the tcl commands can still be retrieved from the perl exe? 
So if this is the case, then how can I protect my tcl commands?

Comment: It seems the focus of your question is about how to hide the input, not how to do it. Perhaps you should rewrite your question so that is more apparent. It's not even in the title.

Comment: @TLP To be clear, Its an XY problem that I have discussed here. I want to do X (protect my tcl script and feed it to vivado console. I am open to all the suggestion on how to do it.) and I have tried to it by using Y (using perl scrip to call vivado and making an executable of perl script. but I stumbled upon the system() function so, I shared my experience). While your answer is partially true that system cannot do it.  I have used pipe to feed commands to vivado console. But I am still left with the protection of tcl script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear, but I think you're asking how to feed a string to a program's STDIN.

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my $script = "...";

run [ "vivado", "-mode", "tcl" ],
   "<", \$script;
```

Do realize that anything you send can easily be captured (e.g. by printing the value of `$script` or by replacing the `vivado` executable).

Comment: This partially answers the question on how to feed command to a program's console (as you call it SDTIN). But what of my intention to protect my tcl script?

Comment: If i use an executable of this perl script, then how will some one be able to print the $script?

Comment: Secondly, if someone can alter the vivado executable, then this would be a disaster for me i guess. It is a totally new idea to me that this could possibly happen, WOW. In that case what can I do?

Comment: I did not call the console STDIN. The program's STDIN has nothing to do with any console.

Comment: _if someone can alter the vivado executable_ - they might just replace it by something simple like `cat > vivado
#! env perl
use 5.028;
while (<>) {say};`

Comment: @clamp That can be shortened to `#!/bin/cat`

Comment: @clamp Understood about the vivado executable but how will someone be able to access the $script variable form the executable?

Comment: Depends on how the executable was built. In general there is no way to hide the source from someone who can run it.

Answer (score -1):

Of the top of my head, having done something like this 25 years ago in 'C', I *think* you want to use the `open()` series of functions with a pipe in there somewhere so that you can `print()` commands to the open connection handle. See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Opening-a-filehandle-into-a-command and maybe even https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3 .